# Open a modal in Slack using Slack API

Tags: apex, slack

I have created a basic Slack app on api.slack.com and successfully implemented a button that can be sent to a Slack channel using Apex. However, I'm currently facing an issue where clicking on the button does not trigger any action.

My desired outcome is to have a modal window appear when the button is clicked, displaying a simple number input field and a submit button. Once the user enters a number and clicks the submit button, I want to send this data back to Apex in JSON format or any suitable format for processing. In the debug I'll see slack user id and number user inputted.

I have attempted various approaches, but so far, the button does not respond when clicked. At a minimum, I would like the button to open the modal window, and ideally, I would like to successfully send the entered number back to Apex. While I understand that it would be helpful to provide the code I have tried, I would prefer to focus on discussing the underlying logic and determining the appropriate steps to resolve this issue. Could you please guide me on the recommended approach for achieving these objectives? Thank you in advance.

---

Bot User OAuth Token:
`xoxb-123.abc.def`

---

In OAuth & Permissions I have Redirect URLs: `https://customOrgIHaveCreated.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/MyCustomAuthSlack`

---

channel id: `ABCD123`

P.S. I don't want to use any external tool like bolt, js, java. Pure apex